# A question about Fourier transformation

Tags: matlab, fourier-transform, linear-systems

[image: the question]

Hello, this is my first time actually asking in stackexchange. I am a computer engineering student and currently i am doing a linear system course (i don't really know how this is equivalent in engineering course labeling as my major is apparently in faculty of computer science but it's related a bit toward signal processing), i hope i wasn't in the wrong category

So I was to find the fourier transformation of the graph in the picture, and i need to plot the graph in matlab as well. I was allowed to look into the table but I couldn't find it hence I used brute force(integrals) to find the $X(\omega)$ of the signal, which i ended up finding but still there's $e^{-\omega.j}$ stuck which confuses me as i believe the plot should be 2 dimensional only (toward x and $\omega$, not toward j). can somebody help finding any faults/things i missed here?

[image: my calculation]

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackExchange! Your question fits here well enough though asking on [Math.Stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com) would have been an alternative. I'd highly recommend you to check out the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) that will show you how you can typeset equations in your question. This will make it much easier for us to read your question.

Comment: thanks @Florian, I'm slowly editing my questions for now

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your integral, it is not quite correct I think. You used partial integration to solve it, which works. Let's consider $\int t {\rm e}^{-\jmath \omega t}{\rm d}t$ and call $f(t) = t$ and $g'(t) = {\rm e}^{-\jmath \omega t}{\rm d}t$ so that $g(t) = -\frac{1}{\jmath \omega}{\rm e}^{-\jmath \omega t}$. Then using $$\int f(t) g'(t){\rm d}t = f(t)g(t)-\int f'(t) g(t) {\rm d}t,$$ we obtain $$\int_0^1 t {\rm e}^{-\jmath \omega t}{\rm d}t = \left[-\frac{t}{\jmath \omega}{\rm e}^{-\jmath \omega t}\right]_0^1 + \frac{1}{\jmath \omega}\int_0^1{\rm e}^{-\jmath \omega t} {\rm d}t.$$ It's close to what you did, but you used $g'(t)$ in the first term instead of $g(t)$.

> ended up finding but still there's e(−ω∗j) stuck which confuses me as i believe the plot should be 2 dimensional only (toward x and ω, not toward j).

Note that $j$ is not a variable! It's the imaginary unit $\sqrt{-1}$. Hence, your expression only depends on one variable, which is $\omega$. Matlab will recognize $j$ as the imaginary unit by default, so you should be all set for plotting it.

Comment: oh yeah i did a calculation mistake, thanks for pointing it out. i do understand that j is $\sqrt{-1}$ but i thought that j is outside the graphs as there's a specific plane which maps $Re$ and $j$ implicitly. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Well, your spectrum will be complex, i.e, for every frequency $\omega$, you will obtain a complex number. You could plot this on two axis for real and imaginary part. It is much more common though to plot the magnitude $|X(w)|$ which is then $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ so it can be displayed as an ordinary function graph. This does then not show the phase information, which can be plotted separately. See [Bode plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bode_plot) for reference.